# How are proportionality constants usually determined?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: c]

Could anyone help me understand how proportionality constants are selected? I've been trying to self-teach differential equations and came across this passage, where the authors are providing an illustration of diff equations being used to solve a concrete problem. It doesn't seem essential to grasp the point they're making, but I'm somewhat dumbfounded about the appearance of the proportionality constant, which they haven't mentioned prior to this. How do you go about determining such constants in real-life problems generally?

Comment: Implicitly the question says that the number of $C^{14}$ atoms which decompose in a small amount of time is proportional to the number of $C^{14}$ atoms which are present. That leads to the constant $k$ of proportionality.  Instead it says "this rate of decomposition of $C^{14}$ varies as the first power of $x$" but it means much the same.  So you count the number of Carbon-14 atoms and then the rate of emission of beta particles as some of it changes to Nitrogen-14 over a period of time, and divide the latter by the former and by the time period for the measurement to get a rate of decay $k$

Comment: For the decay of carbon 14, we have to do measurements and observations to find the value of $k$ to use.  Once that has been done, the rest of us can look it up in reference books.  Of course other radioactive isotopes obey the same differential equation (1.11) but with different constant $k$.

Comment: @Henry, GEdgar, thank you both for immediate, helpful responses.

Comment: @Henry would you be able to break it down for me a bit further? I'd like to totally grasp how "this rate of decomposition of C^14 varies as the first power of x" means what you say it means, just for future reference. What are they referring to with "the first power of x"?